# ASP.NET MVC : my calendar is not taking the model date value when I press edit

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, forms, datetime

I'm creating a form that handles both create and edit requests, if a user presses edit or create in both cases he will go to `Save.cshtml` but if he presses edit the model data should be in the form other wise it should be empty(create) so this is my code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Description" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="Description" id="description" class="form-control" value="@(@Model == null ? "" : @Model.Description)" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Expiraydate" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="Expiraydate" id="expirydate" class="form-control" value="@(@Model == null ? null : Convert.ToString(@Model.Expiraydate))" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Expiraydate" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

It worked with the description but it did not work with the expiry date, note that my model has expiry date as `DateTime`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If 'Expirydate' is a Date in your model, your input in your view should also be a 'date' input type.

The datetime format allowed by 'datetime-local' input is : 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss'.
The datetime format allowed by 'date' input is : 'yyyy-MM-dd'.

For example if you need a date or datetime format you can find examples below :

```html
<label for="Expirydatetime">Date time</label>
<input id="Expirydatetime" name="Expirydatetime" type="datetime-local" value="2021-08-25T15:49:00"/>
<br />
<label for="Expirydate">Date</label>
<input id="Expirydate" name="Expirydate" type="date" value="2021-08-25"/>
```

Try to replace your Expirydate input by this one if Expirydate is only a date:

```
<input type="date" asp-for="Expiraydate" id="Expirydate" class="form-control" value="@(@Model == null ? null : @Model.Expirydate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))" />
```

Or by this one if Expirydate is a datetime :

```
<input type="datetime-local" asp-for="Expiraydate" id="Expirydate" class="form-control" value="@(@Model == null ? null : @Model.Expirydate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "T" + @Model.Expirydate.ToString("HH:mm:ss"))" />
```